# How can I install Windows Server 2016 Standard in English?

Tags: windows-server-2016, language, language-packs

Is there a way to force installation of Windows Server 2016 Standard in English? The only choice in my install iso is German and I cannot choose English which I find very strange. Changing the system language to English via downloading the language pack is not an option because it is not implemented well. Half the system component names and system messages are still German. For example even after downloading and installing the English language pack the component "Device Manager" does not exist but only the German "Geraetemanager".

Anyone know why I cannot choose English from the get-go?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found the answer:

I downloaded the English evaluation version of Windows Server 2016 Standard, installed it but could not enter my product key as I received an error message that the product cannot be upgraded. I then entered the following in powershell:

dism /online /set-edition:ServerStandard /productkey: /accepteula, where  is my product key. And voila, the version was changed from eval to a full license.

Answer (score 1):

Check [my similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1160592/way-to-switch-windows-10-user-interface-to-english) about Windows 10.

For English interface you need to download **English media**.

Comment: Where can I download the English install? Installing the Evaluation version does not work because when I try to enter my key it says "This edition cannot be upgraded"

Comment: @Matt Wolf I do not know what type of license you have. Perhaps it has any restrictions. I believe the correct installation image should be downloaded from the Personal Cabinet Microsoft

Comment: Just found the answer.